# RxAndroid, how to subscribe only "data" array of this response?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I am new to RxAndroid every example shows a List or Collection type that is expected to be parsed from the  onComepleted() method of .subscribe(..) call but the response of my REST API is not a list rather it has a list inside a json object like below ,how to subscribe **only "data"** array of this response?

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly what you want is to select the data field of the returned object. So the answer is simple just map the result `observableReturningTheWholeObject.map { it.data }`